# SQL - Group by the base of an ID

Tags: sql, group-by

My SQL is not really good, but I am improving.

I try to extract records from a table with sales data. I want to know how much profit was made by a retailer and its subsidiaries per month.

The `retailer_id` is build from the root of 5 digits and (if subsidiaries exist) an adjacent _ with two digits. Like so:

- without subsidiaries: 30000
- with subsidiaries: 30000_01, 30000_02

Code:

```
SELECT
    retailer_id,
    MONTH(Date(created_at)) AS month,
    SUM(grand_total) AS Totals
FROM 
    sales_table
GROUP BY 
    retailer_id, month
```

As you can imagine, the retailer with subsidiaries are still separated line items.

As requested, I will give an example:

raw data

| retailer_id | month | grand total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10006 | 12 | 10 |
| 10006 | 9 | 20 |
| 10006 | 9 | 40 |
| 10006_10 | 12 | 40 |
| 10015 | 9 | 10 |
| 10015 | 11 | 10 |
| 10015 | 12 | 5 |
| 10015 | 11 | 20 |

expected result:

| retailer_id | month | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10006 | 12 | 50 |
| 10006 | 9 | 60 |
| 10015 | 9 | 10 |
| 10015 | 11 | 30 |
| 10015 | 12 | 5 |
| 10015 | 11 | 20 |

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is 'left'. As in this one:

```
select 
 left(retailer_id, 5),
 Month(Date(created_at)) AS month,
 sum(grand_total) AS Umsatz
FROM sales_order
WHERE store_id = '2' AND NOT status = 'canceled' AND created_at between '2021-09-01' AND '2022-01-27'
GROUP BY left(retailer_id, 5), month
ORDER BY left(retailer_id,5);
```